# Has anyone seen this Hitchin-like system?

Tags: gauge-theory, dg.differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold and let $P\to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle with connection $A$.  Let $\alpha \in \Omega^1(M;\mathrm{ad}P)$ be a one-form on $M$ with values in the adjoint bundle $\mathrm{ad} P$.  Then consider the equation
$$ F_{A + \alpha} = \tfrac12 [\alpha,\alpha] $$
in $\Omega^2(M;\mathrm{ad}P)$, where $F_{A+ \alpha}$ is the curvature of the connection $A + \alpha$.

This equation is reminiscent of the Hitchin equations on a Riemann surface, but of course is different.

(In the context in which I have seen this equation, it is supplemented by the condition $\nabla^A \alpha \in \Omega^2(M;\mathrm{ad}P)$, which is equivalent to the vanishing of the symmetrisation of $\nabla^A \alpha$.)

---

**Question**

Has anyone come across such an equation before?  And if so, could you point me to a reference?

Comment: Since $F_{A+\alpha}=F_A + d_A\alpha + \frac{1}{2}[\alpha,\alpha]$, you mean $F_A + d_A\alpha=-[\alpha,\alpha]$, right? And did you mean supplemented by $d_A\alpha=0$?  i.e. you *dont* mean just the second order obstruction to deforming a flat connection? 

Comment: @Paul: Perhaps I should have written the original version of the equation, which is $F_A + \nabla_A \alpha = 0$, whereas $d_A \alpha$ is the skew-symmetrisation of $\nabla^A\alpha$.  In other words, the equation breaks up into two: $F_A + d_A \alpha = 0$ and the vanishing of the symmetrisation of $\nabla^A \alpha$.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: $\nabla_A$ above should be $\nabla^A$.  (I continue to wish I could easily edit comments.)


Comment: I'm still confused by the sign: $F_A+d_A\alpha=0$ is the same as
$F_A+d_A\alpha+\frac{1}{2}[\alpha,\alpha]=\frac{1}{2}[\alpha,\alpha]$
which in turn is $F_{A+\alpha}=\frac{1}{2}[\alpha,\alpha]$. 

In any case, I've never seen this. (As you probably know) if $A$ is flat, then $d_A\alpha=0$ is the first obstruction to $A+t\alpha$ being a path of flat connections and $[\alpha,\alpha]=2d_A\alpha$ is the second obstruction.

 Maybe the other equation is hidden form of some gauge-fixing condition? (are you on a 2-manifold? can you relate d_A^*\alpha=0$ to $Sym(\nabla^A\alpha=0)$?)

Comment: Ah... my apologies.  The sign is wrong!  I must have copied it wrong.
I'll edit.


Comment: OK, but then when $A$ is flat, this is equation $d_A\alpha=0$
which says $\alpha$ represents a class in $H^1(M; g_A)$, and is the linearization of the curvature map at $A$. In this case your pair reduces to just $\nabla^A\alpha=0$. Since $\nabla^A:\Omega^0(T^*M\otimes ad P)\to \Omega^1(T^*M\otimes ad P)$ (I assume the Riemannian metric is used also to define $\nabla^A$),then the the kernel of $\nabla^A$ is finite-dimensional. So at least when $A$ is flat, it reduces to some semi-fredholm linear equation that approximates the tangent space to the moduli space of flat connections at $A$. (?)